# Session storage values not showing up with convertered to pdf

Tags: session, pdf, storage

Hi i am having trouble getting the session storage value to show up on the pdf when i convert it. It shows on the page no problem but can not get it to show on the pdf. Can anyone point me in the right direction thanks i am using  pdfcrowd converter

Comment: Can you add more details to the question? It is unclear what you are looking for.

Comment: i have a table that uses sessionStorage to get values from other pages on the website when i go to this page all the values from session storage are shown on the page but when i hit the download pdf button all the values are gone from the pdf